# Reversing single linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I tried to revert single linkied list as follows:

```
public class MutableLst<T> {
    public T current;
    public MutableLst<T> next;

    private MutableLst(T current){
        this.current = current;
    }

    public static <T> MutableLst<T> create(T current){
        return new MutableLst<T>(current);
    }

    public void reverse(){
        MutableLst<T> newNext = null;
        MutableLst<T> nxt = next;
        next = newNext;
        while(nxt != null) {
            newNext = this;  //<------- cycle is here
            current = nxt.current;
            next = newNext;
            nxt = nxt.next;
        }
    }
```

But this implementation does not work. When I assign to `this` I got a cycle. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't think the code enter in the *while* loop, as you never assign a value to *next*, in the code you show us.

Comment: @MarioSantini I do, right before while loop

Comment: Why do you update the value itself (`current`)? just re-link every node it its predecessor

Comment: But predecessor is this... Or I missed something?

Comment: For the next node it is, but at the end of the loop, the next of `this` should be null, no? because it is now reversed, so if it was the first node, it will now be the last

Comment: @OfirWinegarten But how to get the reference to the first node? Unless I create another object/

Comment: The current last node, will be you new first node, you can return it by the function. But, you have to be careful, if this method is not invoked on the first node, you will end up with a broken list.

Comment: @St.Antario yes, with null. And before you assign to *nxt* the value of *next* that is still not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You are reversing only the list, so I don't know why do you want to do something with "this" object. Anyway I think you should just use this:
https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/MutableList.html#reverseThis--

Comment: I just need to relink current list

Comment: For the time of reversing can you just create bidirectional linked list? You could then put all references to your objects there. Then clear your current list and loop through that temp list in reverse order adding elements to your desired list.

Answer (score 0):

I would use recursion, like this:

```
public void reverse(MutableLst<T> previous){
    if (this.current.next !== null) {
        this.next.reverse(this);
    }
    this.next = previous;
}

public void reverse() {
    reverse(null);
}
```

You will need to call reverse to the head of your list. As about your concrete problem, you are changing the next before you get a chance to use it. You might want to do something like this instead:

```
public void reverse(){
    MutableLst<T> previous = null;
    MutableLst<T> currentItem = this;
    MutableLst<T> nxt = null;
    while(currentItem != null) {
        nxt = currentItem.next;
        currentItem.next = previous;
        previous = currentItem;
        currentItem = nxt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code's problem is that you never assign a value to next. Here's my iterative solution to your problem. Also, to make it easier on yourself I would suggested having a head that references the beginning of your linked list.

```
public void reverse() {
    MutableLst<T> prev = null;
    MutableLst<T> curr = head;
    MutableLst<T> next = null;
       while (curr != null) {
           next = curr.next;
           curr.next = prev;
           prev = curr;
           curr = next;
       }
    }
    head = prev;
```